# How to check if a type of keyboard key is press along with CTRL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call functions if a particular key is press together with CTRL (windows system)

to test for a particular keyCode I used **event.keyCode** In this case I got to know the codes for each key. I assumed **17 + 73** will be **CTRL + I**

This doesn't seem to work except if I check of **p** only.

I want to be able to check for CTRL + a particular KEY.
Thank you.

What I tried:

```
//keyboard shorcut to call functions
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {


   if(e.keyCode  === 90){ // I want CTL + I
    e.preventDefault();
    //call image upload func...
    triggerUpload(event,$(".camicon"));
    return false;

}else if(e.keyCode  === 97){ //I want CTL + P
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.status-btn').click();
    return false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(e.keyCode  === 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
 //   CTRL+I
 }
 else if(e.keyCode  === 97 && e.ctrlKey){ 
   // CTRL + P 
 }
```

This should work, check if e.ctrlKey is pressed.